# Running a jQuery from a different page

Tags: jquery

So I have the following files `a.html`, `b.html`, `c.js`. I would like to be able to achieve the following:

When I click on a link on `a.html`, be redirected to `b.html`, and only after `b.html` is completely loaded, then my `c.js` runs and make references to an element of `b.html`. For instance opens a panel.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on a link on a.html, be redirected to b.html

This is just a standard link, so slightly irrelevant to the question

> only after b.html is completely loaded, then my c.js runs and make
>   references to an element of b.html

So you have a c.js that "runs". A simple solution would be to edit c.js and wrap it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // original contents of c.js go here

});
```

And in b.html include jQuery and c.js in the head of the document (in that order).

You could however include the c.js script as the last tag in the body

```
<body>

   ... some contents here ...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="c.js">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In b.html:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  ...  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting for the page to be completely loaded, you'd want to wrap it in `$(window).load()`.

Comment: *"iPhone has no back ticks?"*  On my iPad, I tap the `.?123` key, then long-press the apostrophe, which brings up 4 alternate characters including backtick.

Comment: Well that's neat :) Thanks Keith! Though, the iPhone is not the most useful tool for editing code! Nice when you don't have the iPad around :)